# How to create responsive/sticky footer in bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have page that has footer with the links. I was able to get the sticky footer but when screen is `xs` or `sm` links are overflowing the footer area. Here is example:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 40px);
}

.page-footer {
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Single Page Application</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
            <a class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="MyApp home page" href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank"><img class="img-rounded" src="images/logo.png" alt="MyApp" /></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6">
            <img class="img-rounded brand2" src="images/app.jpg" alt="Img" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav_menu">
          <li><a href="#" data-id="home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-id="contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-id="help">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron my-jumbotron">
        <h2>Single Page Application</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="main_container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
          <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">

          <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane my-tab-pane fade in active">
            <h3>Tab 1</h3>
            <p>Show tab 1.</p>
          </div>

          <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane my-tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Tab 2</h3>
            <p>Show tab 2.</p>
          </div>

          <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane my-tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Tab 3</h3>
            <p>Show tab 3.</p>
          </div>

          <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane my-tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Tab 4</h3>
            <p>Show tab 4.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="page-footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
          <a href="http://link1/" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Link 1">Link 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
          <a href="http://link2/" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Link 2">Link 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
          <a href="http://link3/" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Link 3">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
          <a href="http://link4/" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Link 4">Link 4</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
          <p class="text-center">&copy; Copyright Name 2018</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see in example they are stacked vertically. I'm wondering how to organize the footer links? Is there an option to show hide the links or make the footer to scroll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can use bootstrap class `navbar-fixed-bottom` on the footer, and I don't think it's a good to use bootrap inside your footer if it's a small fixed footer, it's not designed to.

But you can add an `overflow-y: scroll;` to your css class `.page-footer` if you want it to scroll. I would personally suggest to rewrite the footer to be horizontal.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.page-footer {
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  color: blue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.copyright {
  margin-top: 2px;
  ;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Single Page Application</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
            <a class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="MyApp home page" href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank"><img class="img-rounded" src="images/logo.png" alt="MyApp" /></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6">
            <img class="img-rounded brand2" src="images/app.jpg" alt="Img" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav_menu">
          <li><a href="#" data-id="home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-id="contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-id="help">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron my-jumbotron">
        <h2>Single Page Application</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="main_container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
          <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">

          <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane my-tab-pane fade in active">
            <h3>Tab 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ullamcorper elit sed ante efficitur, ac ultrices erat ullamcorper. Curabitur in luctus libero. Vivamus eu risus ornare, tincidunt elit quis, hendrerit tellus. Duis ut interdum
              tortor, at placerat sapien. Donec quam urna, egestas mollis elementum quis, dignissim non orci. Suspendisse et feugiat massa. Vestibulum eget augue orci. In ultricies, elit et mattis placerat, nulla nibh dignissim odio, sit amet efficitur
              turpis ex eu sapien. Donec id metus egestas sapien varius consectetur ac vitae est. Sed tincidunt ultrices justo in malesuada. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur vulputate vitae
              urna vel interdum. Integer semper nisl nec dolor volutpat, a pulvinar mauris scelerisque. Suspendisse non augue tincidunt, bibendum nulla eget, ultrices erat. Vivamus fermentum ornare tortor, eget convallis nisl finibus ac. Pellentesque
              eu dapibus metus, sit amet tristique dolor. Sed vel mauris eros. Nunc sollicitudin erat sit amet dolor eleifend, vel tristique libero porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi euismod vitae risus eu egestas. Proin
              egestas lectus ut varius rhoncus. Aenean vitae commodo quam, et vestibulum magna. Donec scelerisque nec mi suscipit dignissim. Cras est risus, aliquet et molestie in, pretium at neque. Praesent porttitor lobortis hendrerit. Pellentesque
              molestie leo nec orci euismod, varius luctus lorem laoreet. Nullam ex turpis, tincidunt vitae orci at, dictum imperdiet libero. Nunc ligula metus, vestibulum in nisl ac, condimentum vestibulum urna. Nullam aliquet pharetra sem vel malesuada.
              Fusce gravida, ligula sit amet tempus interdum, tortor tortor tincidunt nisl, in porta sem eros ultrices eros. Phasellus in maximus lectus, non sagittis ex. Aenean consequat dignissim rhoncus. Nulla facilisi. Duis fringilla iaculis sollicitudin.
              Sed non sollicitudin tellus. Nunc vitae accumsan massa, tempus tempus tellus. Integer justo magna, tristique porttitor tempor et, tincidunt tempor turpis. Nunc condimentum tincidunt nisi, a porta enim lobortis a. Donec porta mattis ligula
              a vulputate. Phasellus ut eros aliquam, semper neque sit amet, finibus arcu. Mauris bibendum eros vitae diam bibendum maximus. Pellentesque faucibus blandit leo sit amet maximus. Ut condimentum risus dui, sed scelerisque sem hendrerit id.
              Suspendisse dolor ante, dictum ac velit sed, ultricies varius risus. Phasellus bibendum dui ultricies dolor aliquam mollis. Sed ut auctor ligula. Aliquam vestibulum, lacus a ornare lobortis, elit metus placerat neque, id sodales lectus lectus
              id lacus. Suspendisse vitae enim rutrum, interdum lorem eget, feugiat enim. Morbi sit amet rutrum enim. Curabitur facilisis est dolor, in aliquam est varius at. Aliquam aliquam est a eros eleifend maximus. Nam rutrum urna non enim mollis
              consectetur. Maecenas tellus nisi, maximus vel tortor at, commodo fringilla orci. Nulla pretium eget lorem et consequat. Integer vulputate metus porttitor, gravida lectus eu, mattis dui. Maecenas porttitor semper leo fringilla porttitor.
              Aenean faucibus molestie risus, ac pulvinar sem posuere sit amet.</p>
          </div>

          <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane my-tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Tab 2</h3>
            <p>Show tab 2.</p>
          </div>

          <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane my-tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Tab 3</h3>
            <p>Show tab 3.</p>
          </div>

          <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane my-tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Tab 4</h3>
            <p>Show tab 4.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="page-footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <a href="http://link1/" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Link 1">Link 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <a href="http://link2/" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Link 2">Link 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <a href="http://link3/" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Link 3">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <a href="http://link4/" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Link 4">Link 4</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 copyright">
          <p class="text-center">&copy; Copyright Name 2018</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the horizontal footer that will work on small screens as well? Also how I can add margin space between content and footer? If I scroll on the small screen tab content is sitting on top of the footer...

Comment: @espresso_coffee I added an example.

Comment: Seems that last row of the text in Tab 1 is covered by footer. Is there a way to add padding or margin to prevent that?

Comment: @espresso_coffee edited the answer, by simply adding a margin.

Answer (score 1):

It's so sample. Add another class in your `page-footer` class like

```
<footer class="page-footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
```